# How to detect when my app is terminated with a swipe?

Tags: android, swipe, lifecycle, terminate, ondestroy

I have an Android existential question:

Does an App's onDestroy() get called when I kill it by swiping it out of the task manager?

If not... how can I detect a "killing" swiping event on the app, and do some final stuff beore it dies?

Answer (score 0):

> onDestroy()
>
> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can
>   happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
>   finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
>   instance of the activity to save space.
>
> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!
>
> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

Instead, rely on `onPause()` and `onStop()` to do any final work before your app goes out of view.

Is your main concern the "swiping" event or just saving data? :)

Comment: Here it's talking about of App onDestroy() and not about Activity onDestroy()